# android ViewPager: unable to switch pages onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i wanted to know if someone can help me solve this issue. I have a button setup and when its clicked, its supposed to navigate to another viewpager page. But everytime its clicked, the app crashes returning the error at onClick at fragmenttab2 class. Here is my Main Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment containing the onClick:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Activity activity = getActivity();

    if (activity != null) {       
        addListenerOnButton();      
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);  
    return view;
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    Button nextfrag = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_nextfrag);
    nextfrag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ViewPager) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.pager)).setCurrentItem(1); 
        }
    });
}
```

}

The log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime com.test.seriessample.FragmentTab1$1.onClick(FragmentTab1.java:58)
```

Comment: can you post your Log errors please? And where do you create your viewPager?

Comment: error log posted. and its in the MainActivity but the adapter is seperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your viewPager is probably `null`. I also see that viewPager itself is a ViewPager and in the onClick you search for *another* ViewPager within that ViewPager which doesn't seem right.

EDIT:

you should add something like  this in your activity

```
public ViewPager getPager() {
    return viewPager;
}
```

And in the onClick of your Fragment

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPager().setCurrentItem(1);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!. this been annoying me for days now.