# Change page on button click ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**UPDATES:** `Logcat has been added to the question`
I actually want to change view ( from one fragment to other. ) on `button Click` i have tried many things but I am unable to do it. I have also wrote a `CustomViewPager` to stop changing pages on swiping the screen. it is working fine.

Here is my code:

**MyFragment**

```
 public CustomViewPager mViewPager;
 public Button next;
 public static int count=0;

 public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message,ArrayList<String> a)

 {

   MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

   Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);

   bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
   bdl.putStringArrayList(EXTRA_ARRAY, a);

   f.setArguments(bdl);

   return f;

 }



 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);

   spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinoptions);
   answer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.answer);
   next = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.next);

   next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);//getItem(-1) for previous  

// it is not working

    }
});

   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    Builtprofile.q.get(0).getOptions();


        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Builtprofile.context,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getArguments().getStringArrayList(EXTRA_ARRAY));
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line); 
       spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



   TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);


   messageTextView.setText(message);



   return v;

 }
 private int getItem() {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
}
```

**Code for my PageAdapter**

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

      private List<Fragment> fragments;


      public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {

        super(fm);

        this.fragments = fragments;

      }

      @Override 

      public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);

      }


      @Override

      public int getCount() {

        return this.fragments.size();

      }

    }
```

**Code for ActivityClass**

```
  public List<Fragment> getFragments(){

      List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

     for(i=0;i<q.size();i++)
     {
      fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(q.get(i).getText(),q.get(i).getOptions()));

     }


      return fList;

    }

  public void fragmentopener()
  {
      List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
  }
```

**Code for myCustomViewPager**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled;


    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isPagingEnabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at adapters.MyFragment$1.onClick(MyFragment.java:71)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-07 15:55:53.254: E/AndroidRuntime(17379):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please indicate line 71 @ `MyFragment`

Comment: Line 71:  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

Comment: point use where you initialize `mViewPager` on your code

Comment: when this logcat error occurs, I mean when you try this   **ViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);** then it occurs? I think **ViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);** will work

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar `mViewPager` is null, OP not initialize that

Comment: and when you call **fragmentopener()** because I think you forgot to **set your adapter** it is null for that so **ViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);** will works I think

Comment: @shayanpourvatan man you rock. seriously, how dumb could I be :/

Comment: @shayanpourvatan you can post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you get `NPE` on line 71 @ `MyFragment`, as you said in comment this line is:

```
 mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
```

so `mViewPager` is null, you need initialize that before using

use following code instead your code:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
```

and `getItem()` is:

```
private int getItem(int i) {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}
```

Comment: i have initialized my view pager, but nothing happens on click of button :/

Comment: what is your mean about nothing happened? did your code get on that line? try with log or debug. try `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` too

Comment: ondebugging, everytime i swipe the view, the getcurrentitem shows me 0

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854783/android-viewpager-get-the-current-view

Comment: i have got it done using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658944/android-viewpager-unable-to-switch-pages-onclick

Answer (score 10):

**Not an Answer though, but read on**

I might be late here, I found a very easy solution from an [online resource](https://awesoham.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/tutorial-using-a-button-to-switch-pages-in-a-viewpager-android-studio/):

In the fragment xml, where you are implementing the next / Previous button add this line to the button xml:

android:onClick="jumpToPage"

Place the cursor inbetween "jumpToPage" - press Alt + Enter:

[image]

Add the related function in your PagerActivity -- Not in the fragment

Now modify the function to this:

```
public void jumpToPage(View view) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
    }
```

Now buy me a [nunchai](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pink-Chai/) :)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you:

### Just put this code on click of button:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
```

### NOTE: in the place of **1** you can pass your number

Comment: its still not working. i have 9 fragments each time it returns a nullpointer error

Comment: @HassaanRabbani i think this might worked, post logcat error maybe you have problem with some where else

Comment: logcat added, please check

Comment: @Darshak because i had already implemented it that way. but i was unable to make it work, that is why i had posted a question here. anyways. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

**Simply do this**

**Next** & **Previous** are two buttons.

```
 previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0)
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount())
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it

```
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < 4) {   
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

the best and the easiest answer is

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
```

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

my code is for kotlin and I thought I could help a lot of people, so I had to write it here.

```
        val fragments: ArrayList<Fragment> =
        arrayListOf(
            HomeFragment(),
            SearchFragment(),
            AddFragment(),
            NotificationsFragment(),
            ProfileFragment()
        )
    binding.viewpager.adapter = FragmentViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, fragments)
    binding.viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 5
    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 1


    binding.viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {

        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            when(position){
                0 -> binding.navigation.selectedItemId = position
                1 -> binding.navigation.selectedItemId = position
                2 -> binding.navigation.selectedItemId = position
                3 -> binding.navigation.selectedItemId = position
                4 -> binding.navigation.selectedItemId = position

            }


        }
    })
    binding.navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { it
        it.let {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 0
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_search-> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 1
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_add -> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 2
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_notifications -> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 3
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_profile -> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 4
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> {
                    binding.viewpager.currentItem = 0
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
        }
```